# PyCharm treats all txt files like requirements file

Tags: python, pycharm, requirements.txt

I have requirements.txt file in my project and PyCharm works perfectly fine with it. However, it also checks every other txt file and displays misleading error messages. For example, having foo.txt file with a string

```
bar baz
```

written in it produces the following message:

```
<versionspec>, RequirementsTokenType.COMMENT, RequirementsTokenType.EOL, RequirementsTokenType.LSBRACE, RequirementsTokenType.SEMICOLON or RequirementsTokenType.WHITE_SPACE expected, got 'baz'
```

I definitely don't want PyCharm to treat all txt files like requirements file, how can I change this strange behavior?

PyCharm 2020.2.1 CE

Comment: I would recommend opening txt files in a different editor, rather than a programming editor. Notepad or nano maybe.

Comment: @Linux4Life531 why should I bother with other editors if I have preferred one, which is one among the best IDEs for Python programming? Fixing such a minor issue like described in the question is better options than switching to another editor.

Comment: Are you using a plugin to check the `requirements.txt` files or is this from the default editor? And how does this error come up?

Comment: Can you check Settings -> Editor -> File Types if there isn't something unusual about requirements? I dont see `requirements.txt` there as a recognized file type at all, so having a plugin for `requirements.txt` handling seems like the most plausible scenario.

Comment: @baduker thanks, I checked and found that this inspection is coming from requirements plugin, not installed by default: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10837-requirements

Answer (score 15):

This behaviour is caused by the [requirements](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10837-requirements/) plugin, you can fix it by removing the patterns as shown bellow:
[image: requirements plugin]

Comment: Great fix.  This gets the "Worst Default Pattern of the Decade" award.  All text files => requirements...  Seriously?

Answer (score -1):

You can also avoid this problem by using markdown suffixes (.md) for non-requirements files.